# Calling functions from bash script within interactive shell on Cloud9.io

Tags: bash

I'm not experienced with shell scripting.  I made this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function hac() {
    echo "test: $1"
    javac $1.java && java $1
}

hac SquareDriver
```

So I have SquareDriver.class in the working directory and this works when I call 
./scriptname.sh

However, I would like to make it so I could just call hac filename on the command line and it would execute the function from within this file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the function definition in your `~/.bashrc`. This will make `hac` available in all your terminal sessions.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry I didn't get back sooner to check on this.